# MySQL LIMIT 20 after X.id

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure how to ask this so i am having a hard time finding answers online... here is something like what I want:

```
SELECT id FROM table ORDER date DESC LIMIT 20, 30 [start after X id]
```

... so the deal is that I am making a paging system... the only problem is that if someone clicks on to page 2 in theory a new entry could have been made pushing the order back so the person could see the last entry of the first page as the first entry on the second page if a new entry has been made since clicking page 2.

What I want is to be able to still limit but tell my limit... hey give me the next 20 after this ID ok? thanks mysql lol.

But yeah sorry if this question is hard to follow like I said its hard for me to put into words what I want so I am having a hard time finding an answer.

Comment: And what should happen when the entry with the id chosen for paging gets deleted?

Comment: bah! Good call i haven't though about that yet... lol one step at a time i suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `WHERE` clause to your SQL Statement

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id > X ORDER date DESC LIMIT 20, 30
```

Comment: is it really that simple? I was thinking that but i'm not at a spot were i can test it just yet. Thanks Craig! --- actually i just got to thinking im using a function in php to create a UUID (so my id's look like this "c4ccc2ef-b454-4a7f-b988-53b3cbb174c3-9cf80e5") so id > x might not work right?

Comment: i should probably just not create a UUID and just use id as INT AUTO INCREMENT huh?

Comment: Ah, yes, this wont really work with a UUID. Auto-inc id would be good. But could could also just use the 'date' as well (well probably only if it acully includes a time too - ie a datetime).

Comment: yea i have a date created which is a time stamp... but wouldn't it be possible that there could be two entries with the same stamp? Maybe i just wont worry about it and if there are new items added and it pushes stuff they have all ready seen to page 2 well then they'll just see it again :P

Comment: OR how ridiculous would it be to return a big ass array of all the rows from the result and then spit them out to a jquery array or something and then just page through it that way? then if they want to see any new items they'll need to refresh the results section?

Answer (score 0):

I think what im going to end up doing is capturing the time the user starts viewing the list and then use Craigs solution based on that time.... then if they refresh the results i'll refresh the time they started viewing.